# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: genre_id, however I annoted it "genreId"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have weird error with hibernate. It says the following in the exceptions:

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: genre_id in movietime2.genres

However I annoted the @Id column of the GenresEntity like this:

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "genreId", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public int getGenreId() {
        return genreId;
    }
```

[Here is the database table.](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/150417/Capture_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg)

Code of GenresEntity class:

```
package com.movietime.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by Attila on 2015-04-16.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "genres", schema = "", catalog = "movietime2")
public class GenresEntity {
    private int movieid;
    private String genre;
    private int genreId;
    @JsonIgnore
    private MoviesEntity movie;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "movieid", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public int getMovieid() {
        return movieid;
    }

    public void setMovieid(int movieid) {
        this.movieid = movieid;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "genre", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 50)
    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "genreId", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public int getGenreId() {
        return genreId;
    }

    public void setGenreId(int genreId) {
        this.genreId = genreId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        GenresEntity that = (GenresEntity) o;

        if (genreId != that.genreId) return false;
        if (movieid != that.movieid) return false;
        if (genre != null ? !genre.equals(that.genre) : that.genre != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = movieid;
        result = 31 * result + (genre != null ? genre.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + genreId;
        return result;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "movieid", referencedColumnName = "movieid", nullable = false)
    public MoviesEntity getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }

    public void setMovie(MoviesEntity movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }
}
```

MoviesEntitiy class:

```
package com.movietime.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Attila on 2015-04-06.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies", schema = "", catalog = "movietime2")
//@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "movieid")
public class MoviesEntity {
    private int movieid;
    private String title;
    private String year;
    private String imdbid;
    //@JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<ActorsEntity> actors;
    //@JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<WritersEntity> writers;
    //@JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<ProducersEntity> producers;
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Movies2ActorsEntity> characters;
    @JsonIgnore
    private MpaaratingsEntity mpaaRating;
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<GenresEntity> genres;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "movieid", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public int getMovieid() {
        return movieid;
    }

    public void setMovieid(int movieid) {
        this.movieid = movieid;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 400)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "year", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 100)
    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "imdbid", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 10)
    public String getImdbid() {
        return imdbid;
    }

    public void setImdbid(String imdbid) {
        this.imdbid = imdbid;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        MoviesEntity that = (MoviesEntity) o;

        if (movieid != that.movieid) return false;
        if (imdbid != null ? !imdbid.equals(that.imdbid) : that.imdbid != null) return false;
        if (title != null ? !title.equals(that.title) : that.title != null) return false;
        if (year != null ? !year.equals(that.year) : that.year != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = movieid;
        result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (year != null ? year.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (imdbid != null ? imdbid.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    //@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    //@JoinTable(name = "movies2actors", catalog = "movietime2", schema = "", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movieid", referencedColumnName = "movieid", nullable = false), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actorid", referencedColumnName = "actorid", nullable = false))
    @Transient
    public List<ActorsEntity> getActors() {
        return actors;
    }

    public void setActors(List<ActorsEntity> actors) {
        this.actors = actors;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "movies2writers", catalog = "movietime2", schema = "",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movieid", referencedColumnName = "movieid", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "writerid", referencedColumnName = "writerid", nullable = false))
    public List<WritersEntity> getWriters() {
        return writers;
    }

    public void setWriters(List<WritersEntity> writers) {
        this.writers = writers;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "movies2producers", catalog = "movietime2", schema = "", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movieid", referencedColumnName = "movieid", nullable = false), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "producerid", referencedColumnName = "producerid", nullable = false))
    public List<ProducersEntity> getProducers() {
        return producers;
    }

    public void setProducers(List<ProducersEntity> producers) {
        this.producers = producers;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie")
    public List<Movies2ActorsEntity> getCharacters() {
        return characters;
    }

    public void setCharacters(List<Movies2ActorsEntity> characters) {
        this.characters = characters;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "movieid", referencedColumnName = "movieid", nullable = false)
    public MpaaratingsEntity getMpaaRating() {
        return mpaaRating;
    }

    public void setMpaaRating(MpaaratingsEntity mpaaRating) {
        this.mpaaRating = mpaaRating;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie")
    public List<GenresEntity> getGenres() {
        return genres;
    }

    public void setGenres(List<GenresEntity> genres) {
        this.genres = genres;
    }
}
```

Why is it searching for a genre_id column?

Comment: I think you don't put a value for movieid. Try to put a value for it like movie2.setValue(1). or to use a generation strategy for the movieid field like : @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

Comment: Can you post the class MoviesEntity

Comment: @Bill Bilal: What do you mean by that? "I think you don't put a value for movieid." In the database? It's full of values. I don't understand it either: "Try to put a value for it like movie2.setValue(1)"

Comment: Also can you post the complete log trace.

Comment: sorry genreId and not movieId since it is the Id.

Comment: try to put this annotation @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) after @Id annotation to see if it works

Comment: First, here is the complete log: http://pastebin.com/DmFkDZZv . Now I try the @GeneratedValue annotiation, but if I remember correctly I already tried it. Update coming.

Comment: I tryed putting @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) after the @Id in GenresEntity class, it didn't help. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: In hibernate.cfg.xml can you check and ensure whether you are connecting to correct database?

Comment: @Balaji If I remove this class from the project, everything is fine, so yes, I'm connecting to the correct database.

Comment: How are you running your code then. Can you check the class file that's  running by opening it in a decompiler and see if your changes have reflected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate is expecting to see a column called `genre_id`and then spitting chips when it can't find that in your DB.  This happens because of the renaming strategy.  You can fix this by setting the rename strategy, such as this for when using Spring JPA:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy
```

You can achieve the same in a 'hibernate.cfg.xml` (I think it is) with just:

```
<property name="hibernate.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your Exception :**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: genre_id in movietime2.genres
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:365)
```

**From the Hibernate Source for Table Class:**

```
ColumnMetadata columnInfo = tableInfo.getColumnMetadata( col.getName() );
if ( columnInfo == null ) {
    throw new HibernateException( "Missing column: " + col.getName() + " in "  
     + Table.qualify( tableInfo.getCatalog(), tableInfo.getSchema(), tableInfo.getName()));
}
```

The possibilities due to which your class is failing could be due to one of the following:

1. You are connecting to a wrong database.
2. Your running class doesn't contain the changes that you have made. You need to check if your classes are properly compiled.

Comment: We can exclude the 1. possibility because if I remove the GenresEntity class from the project everything works fine. I can query the other database tables seamlessly. For example ActorsEntity: http://pastebin.com/z0yxER3A

Comment: How can I check if my classes are properly compiled? I can compile them explicitly in Intellij Idea, by right clicking on them, and clicking on "Compile". Doesn't help.

Comment: How are you running your application? As war or from your ide like a test case

Comment: I'm deploying on Tomcat 8 in debug mode with Intellij Idea.

Comment: So go to your war deployed in webapps folder and open the class file using a java decompiler and see if its properly reflecting your change.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I decided to go with the trivial a workaround. I renamed the column genreId in my database table to genre_id, I changed the references in the Java annotations too, and it works now. So there is no good solution, but at least I can continue my work.